# ¿Alquien me puede ayudar con este error de syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
     class GameObject:
    class_name = ""
    desc = ""
    objects = {}
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    GameObject.object[self.class_name]= self

def get_desc(self):
    return self.class_name + "\n" + self.desc

class Gobling(GameObject):
    class_name ="gobling"
    desc ="A foul creature"

gobling =Gobling("Gobbly")

def examine(noun):
    if noun in GameObject.objects:
        return
GameObject.objects[noun].get_desc()
    else:
    return "There is no {} here.".format(noun)

verb_dict= {
    "say": say,
    "examine": examine,
}


        line 22
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Hola Danny, te recomiendo que tu publicación no incluya únicamente código sino que trates de explicar que deseas realizar con el código que publicas. Para ello, te sugiero que leas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: muchas gracias…

Answer (score 1):

El error que te lanza tu código se debe a la indentación o sangrado no con error de sintaxis. En Python y en otros lenguajes son estrictamente necesarios para que el lenguaje, en este caso Python pueda ser interpretado

En tu caso, la estructura de control `else`debe estar al mismo nivel de indentación que el `if`previo. De igual modo, si la clase es la primera sentencia que posees en tu código no puede estar con sangrado

De igual modo, en la declaración del diccionario tienes unas claves (keys) las cuales no están inicializadas en el propio código, por lo que, te lanzará una excepción tipo `undefined name 'say'` y `undefined name 'examine'` respectivamente

```
class GameObject:
  class_name = ""
  desc = ""
  objects = {}
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    GameObject.object[self.class_name]= self

  def get_desc(self):
    return self.class_name + "\n" + self.desc

class Gobling(GameObject):
  class_name = "gobling"
  desc = "A foul creature"
  gobling = Gobling("Gobbly")

  def examine(noun):
    if noun in GameObject.objects:
      return
      GameObject.objects[noun].get_desc()
    else:
      return "There is no {} here.".format(noun)

verb_dict= {"say": say, "examine": examine}
```